# setup posfix mail server - allow local emails (error 550 5.7.1)

Tags: postfix, email-server, mx-record, email-bounces

I have from on website and submiting it should sens question email to support on behalf of customer (puting his email addres as sender)

Problem is that support does not recieve email but insead customer gets bounce with this error

550 5.7.1 Unconfigured Sending Domain

I'm not sure, but I suppose that means that my mail serve is not able to verifi sender aganist forged email (that it technicakly is) so it refuses it. How do I setup email server to ingonre the check for local emails (email sent from same, or some specified, server)?

Or is problem something else?

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't use the customers email as the "Sender", it's going to cause all kinds of authentication issues. Maybe use it as the "reply-to" field. You can read more about that here: [The Contact Us Form Nightmare](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/resources/dmarccontactus/)